# Not able to access the INIT variable in a secondary FOR loop

Tags: for-loop, syntax-error, abap

I have the following code snippet:

```
TYPES: BEGIN OF ty_table_line,
         idx   TYPE i,
         posnr TYPE i,
         quan  TYPE i,
       END OF ty_table_line,
       ty_internal_table TYPE SORTED TABLE OF ty_table_line WITH UNIQUE KEY idx.

DATA(lt_set) = VALUE ty_internal_table( ( idx = 1 posnr = 1 quan = 2 )
                                        ( idx = 2 posnr = 1 quan = 40 )
                                        ( idx = 3 posnr = 1 quan = 10 )
                                        ( idx = 4 posnr = 1 quan = 88 ) ).

DATA(lt_set_2) = VALUE ty_internal_table(
      FOR i = 0 WHILE i <= 4
      ( LINES OF VALUE #( FOR <line> IN lt_set[]
                          WHERE ( idx = i + 1 )
                          ( <line> ) ) ) ).
```

Here, my loop starts with `i=0` and I am trying to use the value in `i` to filter out some values from an internal table `LT_SET`. What is the right approach for this error?

I tried with `WHERE ( idx = i + 1 )` and `WHERE ( idx <> i )`, but I get this error:

> The variable "I" cannot be used here.

Comment: There are too many missing information (method, parameter and variable types, etc.) Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, it's weird that both parameter and variables have same names (`lt_set`, etc.), so I suspect that the code is globally incorrect, so please clarify by providing minimal reproducible example.

Comment: I edited the question to propose a minimal reproducible example. Please confirm whether it's okay for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't explain the reason (nothing found in the ABAP documentation) but I could reproduce and find a workaround with an additional auxiliary variable declared with `LET`. Tested with ABAP 7.52.

```
TYPES: BEGIN OF ty_table_line,
         idx   TYPE i,
         posnr TYPE i,
         quan  TYPE i,
       END OF ty_table_line,
       ty_internal_table TYPE SORTED TABLE OF ty_table_line WITH UNIQUE KEY idx.
DATA(lt_set) = VALUE ty_internal_table( ( idx = 1 posnr = 1 quan = 2 )
                                        ( idx = 2 posnr = 1 quan = 40 )
                                        ( idx = 3 posnr = 1 quan = 10 )
                                        ( idx = 4 posnr = 1 quan = 88 ) ).
DATA(lt_set_2) = VALUE ty_internal_table(
      FOR i = 0 WHILE i <= 4
      LET j = i IN
      ( LINES OF VALUE #( FOR <line> IN lt_set[]
                          WHERE ( idx = j + 1 )
                          ( <line> ) ) ) ).

ASSERT lt_set_2 = lt_set.
```